# how to set horizontal scrolling in UITableView by using interface builder?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have UITableView in my app with 2 columns.I can read column 1 and half of column 2.My questions are-
can we add horizontal scroll by use of interface builder in uitableview so i can read column 2 for all cells in table?

should we have to add some code for that too or its only possible with interface builder?

Comment: in each row i have two labels leftCellLabel and RightCellLabel and i can see leftCellLabel text as it is small text and  i can see RightCellLabel  but not all the text now i want to scoll horizontally so i can read all text for all cell

Comment: you want to scroll the text or the view itself? maybe a screenshot would help to understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the row in the `UITableView` doesn't scrolls itself inside the `UITableView`.
My solution (I know someone will come out with something better)
Is to use an `UIScrollView` and then inside add the `UITableView`.
This `UIScrollView` will have the same size that your `UITableView` have now, but the `UIScrollView` contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width.
[image]

Comment: great answer! the only problem is that VerticalScroll is then invisible to the user.. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add two columns to UITableView. What i understand is to solve the above problem is create two table view side by side. write code or interface builder as per your requirement

Comment: if your table size is greater than the view size in width then you can scroll the it horizontally using property in Interface builder for table view in Scroll View section #1.  If you want a table to be scrolled horizontally and not vertically then use scroll view and create custom cells and add to the scroll view