# Multi-column Tableview in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In my app, I want to create a multi-column TableView like an Excel Sheet.

The Table View may also greater than the screen size, so I also want scroll it Horizontally.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: To scroll horizontally you can put scrollview on each cell multiple label or view over that scrollview

Comment: The easiest way would be a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Comment: @sanjitshaw, but i don't want to scroll the cell, I want scroll the whole column view like Excel sheet

Comment: Or you can do one thing don't know is it a fine way or not. Put multiple tableview each as a column over a scrollview. But I think it will be complicated to implement.

Comment: check out this question and it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297362/how-to-set-horizontal-scrolling-in-uitableview-by-using-interface-builder .Dear SO users, please try to know your problem well, try to achieve the output in various ways and search more to get the answer before asking same type of questions..

Answer (score 2):

### Pre iOS 6

You'll need to implement it yourself. This isn't available because a very large spreadsheet is difficult to navigate and you should probably rethink your presentation of the data.

Given that warning, you will need to implement this via a `UIScrollView` and managing attachment of your cells to the scrollView yourself. If you attach all the views in advance you will have choppy scrolling, so you want to attach and remove them as they come into view.

You can also check out the [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView) project at Github. This may be exactly what you want.

### iOS 6 UICollectionView

This class feels similar to `UITableView` but it supports grids and any custom layout you can dream up. Check out the videos Introducing Collection Views in the WWDC 2012 videos. It is truly amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Better to choose `UICollectioView` or `UISrollView` instead of  `UITableView`

The `UICollectionView` class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts.

About using  `UITableView`,you can create `custom UITableView cells` by using Interface Builder and loading a custom nib. It's only vertically scrollable

You can see the details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)